# Printing from Android/IOS phone in the enterprise?

Tags: printing, iphone, android

Simple question, possibly complicated answer. What has been your solution for users wanting to print from their Android/iOS devices? Print email attachments, etc directly from the phone to your enterprise class printer? The mobile device would be on a WiFi network in a different vlan (but on the company network).

Answer (score 1):

For iOS, you need an [airprint](http://www.apple.com/iphone/features/airprint.html) enabled printer, or a 3rd party app.

Comment: So originally I was looking at the LaserJet Pro CP1525nw Color Printer (CE875A) as it's airprint enabled. However the remainder of the question is how is Android 3rd party app support? It seems fairly lacking (other than Google CloudPrint).

Answer (score 0):

[File Processor](http://www.fileprocessor.info/support/articles/00008/configure-your-own-mobile-printing-hotspot) works with any device that can send an email...

**Update:** http://www.fileprocessor.info/mobileprinting

*(I'm affiliated with the company)*

Comment: Did/Do you use this program? WindowsDefender SmartScreen and my antivirus program fire up alerts!

Comment: Yes, have it running here... probably a false positive alert. You can check with virustotal.com